# Can't type in react input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-router

I have a simple form with an input field that I can't type on. I first thought the problem was with the `onChange` or the `value` props that were setting the input to readonly, but the fact is that I cant type with the browser suggestions and the state updates perfectly ([See gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RfM1.gif)) it's just that I won't let me type with the keyboard, even after reloading the page.

I also have a Login page that works perfectly except when I log out and redirect back to that page, it won't work until I reload the page, now it will work.

```
<input
value={name}
onChange={handleChange}
name="name"
/>
```

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e:any) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
}
```

Weird thing is that it's in like a readonly state but when I use browser suggestions it works and updates the state.

Here is the whole component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from '../../utils/useForm';

import { CubeType } from '../../interfaces';

//import useStore from '../store/Store';

import { Modal, Button, Row, Col, FormGroup, FormLabel, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

type Props = {
    show: Boolean,
    onClose: () => void,
    cubeTypes: CubeType[]
};

const ModalTimelist = (props: Props) => {
    //const store = useStore();
    const [values, handleChangee] = useForm({ cubeType: 1, name: '' });


    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e:any) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
        if(modal) modal.removeAttribute('tabindex');
    }, [props.show]);

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={props.show} onHide={ props.onClose }>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Timelist { name }</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="3">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <FormLabel>Cube Type</FormLabel>
                                <select
                                    value={values.cubeType}
                                    onChange={ handleChangee }
                                    className="form-select"
                                    name="cubeType"
                                >
                                    {props.cubeTypes.map((it, idx) => {
                                        return (<option value={ idx } key={"cube"+idx}>{it.name}</option>);
                                    }) }
                                </select>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="9">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                                <FormControl
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="name"
                                />
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="success" onClick={() => props.onClose()}>
                        Save
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={() => props.onClose()}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}

export default ModalTimelist;
```

Comment: Can you add your code for the handleChange ?

Comment: You're going to need to post handleChange and how you're storing state

Comment: hey have chacked the console

Comment: Yes checked the console, no errors

Comment: have you have checked that on change event is fired or not using console some time its happen with the react-bootstrap modal

Comment: what is the useEffect doing exactly?

Answer (score 2):

value of input must be the state value otherwise it will not change use this code

```
const App = () => {
   const [name,setName] = useState("")
   const handle = ({target:{value}}) => setName(value)
   return <input
     value={name}
     onChange={handle}
      name="name"
    />
}
```

Comment: Sorry I do actually have it like you, just forgot to edit. I have the same you posted and not working. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: can you post the whole component please

Comment: Just did! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a debounce for setting name on state.

Example:

```
const handleChange = (e:any) => {
    debounce(() => { setName(e.target.value) }, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Names specified by you in input field attributes must be same as useState names. Otherwise this problem occurs.

**Example:**

```
<input type={"text"} className="form-control" placeholder='Enter your User Name' name="username" value={username} onChange={(e)=>onInputChange(e)}/>
```

In **name="username"** , username spell must be same as the spell you used in State.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and it works fine I think you should change the browser

and if you want

change this

```
const ModalTimelist = (props: Props) => {
```

with

```
const ModalTimelist:React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
```

Comment: Tried with a different browser and still not working. Tried on an older branch and it works so... I'll just have to investigate changes I guess.

Comment: maybe the problem with the library that you use  for ui ,if you use alpha version  change it with stable version

Comment: any luck ? I am running into the same issue.