# Can't type in React TextField Input

Tags: reactjs, textfield

I have added a simple TextField from Material-UI into my landing page but cannot type in the React input field. I'm not sure what is causing the issue and have double-checked the following issues:

- [Proper casing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006333/cant-type-in-react-input-text-field) of `onChange` (not `onchange`)
- [Input value must be the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784348/cant-type-in-react-input-field)
- `this.state` vs `state`; the former causes a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')`.
- `type="text"` vs. `type="number"`; both options don't allow for typing in the text field

Below is my code for the `TextField`, declaring `state`, and handling the change in input field.

```
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
...
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    ImageNumber: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.number]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
...
    <TextField label="" number="ImageNumber" type="text" value={state.ImageNumber} variant="outlined" onChange={handleChange} />
```

Comment: Do you see that your onChange method is called using logs or debugging?

Comment: Are you sure `event.target.number` comes up as `ImageNumber` in the handleChange handler function?

Comment: @dw_ good find, I console logged event.target.number, and typing in the textfield shows undefined in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
...
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    ImageNumber: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
...
    <TextField label="" name="ImageNumber" type="text" value={state.ImageNumber} variant="outlined" onChange={handleChange} />
```

Instead of a non-existent `<input />` element props `number`, you can use the `name` attribute, which shouldn't show `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

- Keep state lean ( dont specify state as an object )
- pass event object to `handleChange` method

```
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
...
 const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState(event.target.value);
  };
...
    <TextField label="" number="ImageNumber" type="text" value={state} variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
```

Comment: This worked! But do you have any recommendations if this is meant to be one of many text fields and the lean approach isn't sustainable?

Comment: @Henrik yes just simply create more states for those fields